# How to insert data into mysql table without duplicating with python?

Tags: python

if input data and data which is already inserted into database are the same,how can i insert data without duplicating? it is better to update the already existing one.but i dont know how to.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO ftp(a,b,c,d) VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s)"
```

Comment: You should make a checker to know whether it's exist. And then take an action to update or create new record

Comment: ya i want to check only one column in database.if input data and data in that column are the same,i want to update the whole row or skip inserting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-mysql-insert-record-if-not-exists-in-table/) article

In short:
You have to check if those values exist in your database or not and then insert.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert data as below.

```
import mysql.connector


def main(config):
    output = []
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
    cur = cnx.cursor()

    # Drop table if exists, and create it new
    stmt_drop = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS names"
    cur.execute(stmt_drop)

    stmt_create = (
        "CREATE TABLE names ("
        "    id TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, "
        "    name VARCHAR(30) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, "
        "    info TEXT DEFAULT '', "
        "    age TINYINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT '30', "
        "PRIMARY KEY (id))"
    )
    cur.execute(stmt_create)

    info = "abc" * 10000

    # Insert 3 records
    names = (('Geert', info, 30), ('Jan', info, 31), ('Michel', info, 32))
    stmt_insert = "INSERT INTO names (name, info, age) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
    cur.executemany(stmt_insert, names)
    cnx.commit()

    # Read the names again and print them
    stmt_select = "SELECT id, name, info, age FROM names ORDER BY id"
    cur.execute(stmt_select)

    for row in cur.fetchall():
        output.append("%d | %s | %d\nInfo: %s..\n" % (
            row[0], row[1], row[3], row[2][:20]))

    # Cleaning up, dropping the table again
    cur.execute(stmt_drop)

    cur.close()
    cnx.close()
    return output


if __name__ == '__main__':

    config = {
        'host': 'localhost',
        'port': 3306,
        'database': 'test',
        'user': 'root',
        'password': '',
        'charset': 'utf8',
        'use_unicode': True,
        'get_warnings': True,
    }

    out = main(config)
    print('\n'.join(out))
```

Regards!